# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS when accessing an NSManagedObject's Property

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In my NSManagedObjects I have some properties that A) I do not want or need stored and B) are only computed once and only when they are needed so that the computations are not repeated (since they are somewhat expensive).

Here is the code I am talking about:

```
public class Sample: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged public var anotherProperty: String?
    var orderedCustomObjects : Array<CustomObject>?

    func getOrderedCustomObjects() -> [CustomObject] {
        // application crashes on this line.
        if (orderedCustomObjects == nil) {
            // compute the custom object array here.
        }
        return orderedCustomObjects!
    }
}

public class CustomObject {
    var price : String?
    var quantity : String?
}
```

I am getting the following crash on a seemingly harmless line that checks if the property is nil before computing it:

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000048

Any help would be appreciated on why I might be getting a crash from this.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACESSS means that the memory of the object that you are accessing has been deallocated. So the problem is not about nil checking, the problem is because you are accessing the object whose memory has been deallocated.

Comment: Are you deleting this object some where ? Keep in mind Sample is an NSManagedObject subsclass. In 1 NSManagedObjectContext there can be only 1 object that represents a record in your entity. If you have 2 of them they would be the same instance, so if you delete 1 and access through the other you might be in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the answer was that the object was being deleted on a different thread which caused it to be deallocated on the main thread.